# Get subset of DataFrame where certain columns meet certain criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, mask

How can I cleanly make a subset of my DataFrame, where my desired columns meet certain criteria?

Take the following **`DataFrame`** as an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0, 1, 2], 
                        [2, 3, 4], 
                        [4, 5, 6], 
                        [6, 7, 8]], 
                  columns= ["a", "b", "c"])
```

I have a boolean array that indicates which columns from my **`DataFrame`** that I would like to apply a filter:

```
bool_arr = np.array([True, False, True])
```

I also have an array that holds the threshold values for each column. For each column where the **`bool_arr`** holds **`True`**, The row value needs to be below the threshold value:

```
thresh_arr = np.array([3, 2, 7])
```

The DataFrame subset that should result from my filtering/masking is the following:

```
  "a" "b" "c"
0  0   1   2
1  2   3   4
```

I was able to get this DataFrame subset with the following code, but it is not as clean as I would like:

```
sel_cols = df.columns[bool_arr]
sel_thresh = thresh_arr[bool_arr]
df_masked = df[sel_cols] < sel_thresh
sel_rows = df.index[df_masked.sum(axis=1) == bool_arr.sum()]
df_subset = df.loc[sel_rows]
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to make this shorter and cleaner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to do it with Pandas [Index.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html), [pipe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html), and [lt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html):

```py
df_subset = df[
    df.index.isin(
        df.loc[:, bool_arr]
        .pipe(lambda df_: df_[df_.lt(thresh_arr[bool_arr])])
        .dropna()
        .index
    )
]

print(df_subset)
# Output
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  2  3  4
```